# primary key problems in c# asp.net inserting in data base

Tags: c#, sql

I have been trying to insert a record into my data base by clicking on a button for sign up and i have always an exception thrown that the primary key column cannot accept nulls and after doing the try and catch it always get the catch part and do not insert an anything, although it is working well in the sql query

```
enter code here
```

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace dbproject
{
    public partial class StudentReg : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           

        }

        protected void Sign(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            String connStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GUCera"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            String first = firstname.Text;
            String last = lastname.Text;
            String pass = password.Text;
            String mail = email.Text;
            String address1 = address.Text;
            int bit = 3;
            
            try
            {
                if (gender.SelectedItem.Text == "female")
                {
                    bit = 1;

                }

                else if (gender.SelectedItem.Text == "male")
                {
                    bit = 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    Response.Write("you must choose gender");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                Response.Write("" +
                    "please choose your gender  ");
            }


            if (first == "" || last == "" || mail == "" || pass == "" || address1 == "" || gender.SelectedItem.Text == null)
            {
                Response.Write("you must write all info");
            }
            else
            {


                SqlCommand studreg = new SqlCommand("studentRegister", conn);
                studreg.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@first_name", first));
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@last_name", last));
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", pass));
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", mail));
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gender", bit));
                studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@address", address1));


                conn.Open();

               try {
                    studreg.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
           catch(Exception)
            {
                    Response.Write("kk");
            }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Check Your  "studentRegister" Store Procedure. It may have Some issue about Primary Key. Can you Please Show Your Store Procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

In this way, you can open and run a new query in your database. Thus, PK numbers will be set automatically by incrementing them one by one.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD yourPKID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Or you can edit the related column in this way on the UI.

[image]

Or you can finally create a new GUID in c #. You can cast the string according to its type.

```
studreg.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@YourIdColumn", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your columns is set to be your primary key and your studentRegister procedure is not setting this columns value. Try modifying this column to have the AUTO_INCREMENT property.